# Multiple if statement to add to arrayList java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am reading in a textfile into my class. I would like to add to a specific arrayList when the if condition is met. At the moment the arrayList keeps on being written over and I don't know why. Here is the code:

The calling class:

```
public String PatternPDF (String s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String>arr=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Fields2Extract.txt"))){
            //System.out.println(line);
            arr.add(line);
        }
        for (String pattern:arr){
            OrganisePDF(pattern,s);
        }
        return pattern;
    }
```

The arrayList class

```
public void  OrganisePDF (String pattern,String s) {
    ArrayList<String> Chicago =new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern patternorganise = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcherpatternorganise_pattern = patternorganise.matcher(s);
    String h="";
            while (matcherpatternorganise_pattern.find()){
                 h=matcherpatternorganise_pattern.group(0);
                 all.add(h);
            }


            for (String n:all){
                if(n.contains("something good")||n.contains("a load of buses")){
                    n=n.replaceAll("\\n", "").trim();
                    Chicago.add(n);
                       }
            }

    System.out.prinln("Chicago"+Chicago);
}
```

This gives me

```
Chicago[something good]
Chicago[a load of buses]
```

Whereas I'm hoping for

```
Chicago[something good,a load of buses]
```

Comment: this is fragment of bigger code, kind of loop, and here is problerm

Comment: Please provide the code needed to reproduce. It's impossible for the code above to produce and print out the two lines.
As Jacek mentioned, this seems to be nested in a loop, resulting in your array `Chicago` being re-initialized.

Comment: See comment below. Jacek claim as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because you are not concatenating the results in the match of the regex.

try something like appending the match in a stringbuilder and after the for loop add it to chicago list:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String n:all){
    if(n.contains("something good")||n.contains("a load of buses")){
        n=n.replaceAll("\\n", "").trim();
        sb.append(n);
    }

}
Chicago.add(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Still get the same problem. Could this be a newline problem? I thought I had got rid of them all but the stringbuilder seems to concatenate lots of empty strings- perhaps it is adding the lines where the if is not satisfied but without the text?

Comment: Hmm. Possibly because its being called from a loop in another method in the class?

Comment: I fixed it by just putting my ArrayLists outside of the method that was being called- as pointed out it was reinitialising the ArrayList as the method aws being called in a loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
list.add(1, object1)
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String n:all){
    if(n.contains("something good")||n.contains("a load of buses")){
        n=n.replaceAll("\\n", "").trim();
        builder.append(n);
        Chicago.add(0,builder.toString()); //this will add the data to a specific position
    }
}
```

i dont know why you want to do this weird thing , but you can try it this way `chicago.add(0,ojec);` this will add data to given position each time its called.